# Python scripts cannot find ttyACM0 Serial port

Tags: 14.04, python, serial-port, arduino

I have a Arduino Mega 2560 sending data out, my environment is Ubuntu 14.04, it's a python ROS node.

Problem is that it works well when I use Serial Monitor or Plotter in Arduino IDE to see the data coming, but when I run my python scripts, it went wrong, this is my python scripts:

```
import serial
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('robot_skin')
import rospy
from robot_skin.msg import FloatArray


def setup_serial(dev_name, baudrate):
try:
    serial_dev = serial.Serial(dev_name, timeout=1)
    if(serial_dev == None):
        raise RuntimeError("robotis_servo: Serial port not found!\n")

    serial_dev.setBaudrate(baudrate)
    serial_dev.setParity('N')
    serial_dev.setStopbits(1)
    serial_dev.open()

    serial_dev.flushOutput()
    serial_dev.flushInput()
    return serial_dev

except (serial.serialutil.SerialException), e:
    raise RuntimeError("robotis_servo: Serial port not found!\n")

def get_adc_data(serial_dev, num_adc_inputs):
    ln = serial_dev.readline()
    l = map(int, ln.split(','))
    if len(l) != num_adc_inputs:
        rospy.logwarn('Something fishy with the serial port.')
        serial_dev.flush()
        l = get_adc_data(serial_dev, num_adc_inputs)
    return l


if __name__ == '__main__':

dev_name = '/dev/ttyACM0'

baudrate = 115200

serial_dev = setup_serial(dev_name, baudrate)

pub = rospy.Publisher('/arduino/ADC', FloatArray)
rospy.init_node('adc_publisher_node')

for i in range(10):
    ln = serial_dev.readline()

rospy.loginfo('Started publishing ADC data')

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    fa = FloatArray()
    fa.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    fa.data = get_adc_data(serial_dev, 6)
    pub.publish(fa)

serial_dev.close()
```

when I run this, it goes to serial_dev == NONE, have a error.

I have googled a long time to so solve this, I made two changes but this still not working:

1. I used and then Serial Monitor and Plotter in my Arduino IDE works after this: `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0`
2. I added myself to the dialout group use`sudo adduser $USER dialout`

But still have the same error......

Thank you.

Comment: Did you log out/in after the `sudo adduser $USER dialout`?

Comment: The `sudo adduser $USER dialout` is enough , you **don't** need to run `chmod`. As  *waltinator* said log out/in after run `adduser`.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I did, I logged out once when I added to dialout, and today I rebooted my computer once. I just logged out and logged in again, I didn't run chmod, my Arduino IDE Serial Monitor and Plotter works well, but when I run my python code, same problem.....

Comment: it's interesting that my arduino board blinks everytime I hit enter to run my python code, just like it would also blink if I run the Serial Monitor and Plotter in Arduino IDE